# Birational map between reduced schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am reading Ravi Vakil's notes "Foundation of Algebraic Geometry" and in Proposition 6.5.5., it states the following: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are reduced schemes. Then $X$ and $Y$ are birational if and only if there is a dense open subscheme $U$ of $X$ and a dense open subscheme$V$ of $Y$ such that $U$ and $V$
are isomorphic.

It has a short proof and I am not sure about two things from the "only if " direction, and I would appreciate any clarification.

The proof goes as follows. First he finds dense open subschemes $X_1 \subseteq X$ and $Y_1 \subseteq Y$ along with $F: X_1 \rightarrow X$ and $G: Y_1 \rightarrow Y$, whose composition in either order is the identity where it is defined. 
Then he defines for $n>1$, $X_{n+1} = F^{-1}(Y_n)$ and $Y_{n+1} = G^{-1}(X_n)$.
In this case, we have $G \circ F |_{X_2} = id_{X_2}$ and $F \circ G |_{Y_2} = id_{Y_2}.$
Let $X_{\infty} = \cap_{n \geq 1} X_{n}$ and $Y_{\infty} = \cap_{n \geq 1} Y_{n}$. He claims that
$X_2 = X_{\infty}$ and $Y_2 = Y_{\infty}$, from which it follows that $F$ and $G$ define maps between $X_2$ and $Y_2$. These are inverse maps and we are done.

The two things I don't get is:

1. How is $X_2 = X_{\infty}$? (and similarly for $Y_2 = Y_{\infty}$ )
2. Where in the proof are we using the fact that this is a reduced scheme?

Thank you!

Comment: I think at the start of the notes (last I checked) he says that 6.5.5 needs to be rewritten. As it is now the given proof doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Maybe it's good to first read the proof in Hartshorne I.4 for varieties.

Comment: @Hoot Yes, you are right! It says so in the currently available newest version (April 29, 2015). I am reading a slightly older version so I didn't know about it. Thank you very much!